# dpkg add armhf architecture doesn't work - 404 not found

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, arm, docker

Inside a new ubuntu 14.04 docker container I'm trying to add the armhf architecture to dpkg in order to install some armhf libraries using apt-get.
As a result of running:

```
root@2a5e4bdf05b7:/# dpkg --add-architecture armhf
root@2a5e4bdf05b7:/# apt-get update
```

I received:

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [58.5 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [59.7 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [59.7 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed Release [110 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources [1335 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources [5335 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources [7926 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages [1743 kB]          
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages [16.0 kB]    
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages [7589 kB]      
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [161 kB]          
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [1250 B]    
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [107 kB]      
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [428 kB]   
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [6341 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [271 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [55.9 kB]        
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [40 B]     
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [11.4 kB]    
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [185 kB]  
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [40 B]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [60.6 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main amd64 Packages [180 kB]  
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages [40 B]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main armhf Packages                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted armhf Packages                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe armhf Packages                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main armhf Packages               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted armhf Packages         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe armhf Packages           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main armhf Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted armhf Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe armhf Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main armhf Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted armhf Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Fetched 20.4 MB in 23s (858 kB/s)                                              
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried this on a debian jessie container and it worked fine.
Any help is appreciated =)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct way to fix name resolution from Docker container?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163/what-is-correct-way-to-fix-name-resolution-from-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. You need to mark the various deb (not deb-src) lines in your sources-list with [arch=amd64, arch=i386] for all except whichever site you added for the armhf packages, which would want to be marked with [arch=armhf].

That said, proceed with caution. I'm trying this on precise, and when I try installs, it wants to uninstall most of my stuff, including import base files without which the system can't work.

Of course, this may not at all apply to you.

Good luck.