# What is correct way to fix name resolution from Docker container?

Tags: 16.04, networking, dns, docker, container

I have clean Ubuntu MATE 16.04.6 LTS installed.
I installed Docker from repository here with:

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```

and added my user to `docker` group with

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

then I downloaded Ubuntu 19.04 container with

```
docker pull ubuntu:19.04
```

and tried to run `apt update` inside it

```
docker run -it ubuntu:19.04 apt update
```

but got network errors:

> ```
> $ docker run -it ubuntu:19.04 apt update
> Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                   
>   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
> Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease         
>   Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
> Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease           
>   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
> Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
>   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
> Reading package lists... Done        
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> All packages are up to date.
> W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  Temporary
> failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
> W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/InRelease 
> Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
> W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/InRelease 
> Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
> W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-security/InRelease 
> Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
> W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
> ```

The `/etc/resolv.conf` inside container is the following:

> ```
> $ docker run -it  ubuntu:19.04 cat /etc/resolv.conf
> # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
> #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
>
> nameserver 8.8.8.8
> nameserver 8.8.4.4
> ```

The host system has internet, the NetworkManager is used with default settings:

> ```
> $ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
> [main]
> plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
> dns=dnsmasq
>
> [ifupdown]
> managed=false
> ```

all files on the system are unchanged - the `debsums --changed --all --silent` command returns nothing.

The requested output of `iptables -S` is below:

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

Which settings should I change to fix DNS (name resolution) from Docker container?

Notes:

1. I know about disabling DNS masquerading (`#dns=dnsmasq`), but I do not want to use this option.
2. I got the same result while using Docker-CE from docker.com.
3. The system installed from netinstall mini.iso does not suffer from aforementioned problem. It uses `ifupdown`. So the NetworkManager is the root of this problem.

Comment: I never used the `docker.io` package from the universe repo. Any specific reason you need that one? Otherwise I'd suggest uninstalling it and trying `docker-ce` from Docker's own official repo instead. Follow https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

Comment: Thanks, but Docker CE does not change the behaviour.

Comment: Check your firewall rules (e.g. `sudo iptables -S`). Maybe you're blocking traffic on the virtual interface docker uses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution for `docker run` is very simple - we need to choose host network with `--network host` option:

```
docker run -it --network host ubuntu:19.04 apt update
```

and then the problem will be solved.

---

But it also should be noted that `docker build` has `--network` option only starting only [from 18.04 LTS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/docker-build.1.html). So if we need `docker build --network host` for 16.04 LTS we need to use `docker-ce` package from docker.com.

Comment: Whilst this does work, you shouldn't _need_ to bind to the host's network to be able to perform DNS lookups.

Answer (score 0):

On the host machine, I ran `sudo vim /etc/default/docker` and un-commented this line:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"
```

Then restarted Docker with `sudo service docker restart`.

I'm a newbie at Docker, and don't know how these options work, but it seems to have done the trick!