# unable to update ubuntu Docker container using apt-get update

Tags: apt, 18.04, docker

when I run ubuntu as Docker container and when I run `apt-get update` command it gives error and fails to update the repos.

Here is what error I'm getting :

`root@df167e514b29:/# sudo
bash: sudo: command not found
root@df167e514b29:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease

  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease

  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@df167e514b29:/#`

Comment: How do enter the Docker container? What is the host system? See https://askubuntu.com/a/1162198/66509 for possible solution.

Comment: actually I got solution for this thing.
the problem was that internet connection I am using is at enterprise level, so I need to manually setup DNS server for docker. this thing sorted out the problem.

Comment: I'll recommend you to write an answer for your question. This will help other users if they face the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with Internet connection, as mine connection is at enterprise level and because of that It was unable to execute `apt-get update` command.
Solution worked for me is :

1. find your DNS server address using `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
2. Open Docker confg file and uncomment `DOCKER_OPTS` and add your DNS server over there

Docker config file : `sudo gedit /etc/default/docker`

Comment: What solved it for me is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163#1162198.