# How to bypass Hash Sum check for apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, checksums, mssql, hash

I have ubuntu 16.04 based vms and dockers using mssqlserver driver 17. Installed the classic way

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 

sudo apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
```

Since this morning and an update on microsoft side the apt-get update after adding the repo fails  `E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  Hash Sum mismatch`

I followed any lead i could find here ([Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)) to clean apt cache etc. And compared on several machines, either vms, docker containers, even an azure databricks spark instance, same error everywhere so it seems to definitely be an error on the microsoft repo (that, I checked, received an update early this morning).

Is there a way to temporary avoid the hash check to allow my script to bypass that error or am I condemned to wait for M$ to update their repo ?

Comment: I too am having issues now when building docker images. While running apt update on my desktop apt prompted me saying they had changed some values (Origin, Label, Suite, Codename) and wanted me to confirm that I wanted to do these changes. Might be related?

Comment: Looks like they have fixed it now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct way to fix name resolution from Docker container?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163/what-is-correct-way-to-fix-name-resolution-from-docker-container)

Comment: How can this question be "highly active" and yet not attract one single answer? Seriously?

Comment: @Henke simple explanation : There is no way to bypass the hash sum check so there is no good answer to this question, BUT that was a real issue involving a popular Microsoft package (They published a corrupted version to the repo and users were not able to install the package for a few days).

(By the way the link you provided in your previous comment is unrelated)