# Docker build apt-get errors using ubuntu:18.04 base image

Tags: 18.04, apt

My Docker image builds repeatedly keep failing with one of the following two errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/ff7fd80e902a1acfba06e7b513711da31abe915d95b3ba39ce198e02efd209e5  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:1343916 [weak]
    - SHA256:ff7fd80e902a1acfba06e7b513711da31abe915d95b3ba39ce198e02efd209e5
    - SHA1:edd753d5bd860c126016feca4e898a736999915b [weak]
    - MD5Sum:9f666ceefac581815e5f3add8b30d3b9 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:e243776bf91c4d182410fe03e2b925c9fcfead68718b4caa09d20e8e46cf7c95
    - SHA1:d7625072bd6ad2f0f5c9af714088954624914361 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:14d1513c9ae5124fd53e092c82c408f8 [weak]
    - Filesize:1343916 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 17:43:25 +0000
   Release file created at: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 23:37:48 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If I keep trying to build the image repeatedly, I'll get past that maybe 50% of the time only for it to die with the following error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/boost1.65.1/libboost-wave1.65-dev_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What's going on here? How do I fix these issues and get my docker image build to `apt-get` without errors? For what it's worth, I don't have these problems if I use ubuntu:16.04 as my base image (instead of ubuntu:18.04).

```
% docker build --network=host -t myimage:v18.04
```

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Configure environment
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    TZ=America/New_York \
    HOME=/root

# Install packages
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get -y upgrade \
 && apt-get -y install \
        automake \
        autoconf \
        libtool \
        make \
        curl \
        gcc-8 \
        g++-8 \
        git \
        gperf \
        libboost-all-dev \
        libevent-dev \
        libhiredis-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libtokyocabinet-dev \
        tcsh \
        python3-sphinx \
        uuid-dev \
        wget \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# And then other stuff.... But the Docker build never even gets past the previous RUN far.
```

Comment: Run the apt-get update and upgrade manually. Read the output carefully for errors or warnings. Do not use the -y flag when you have problems - it suppresses valuable clues in the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct way to fix name resolution from Docker container?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163/what-is-correct-way-to-fix-name-resolution-from-docker-container)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)