# Ubuntu 18.04LTS in VM; apt-get upgrade results in "Hash Sum mismatch"; overall weird behaviour

Tags: apt, upgrade, virtualization

first of all thanks for your help!I have a weird situation here. I am running several VMs on a ESXi white box and one of the Linux VMs started acting weirdly.

I cannot perform apt-get upgrade or any other install (docker container) as the installs always fail with "**Hash Sum mismatch**". If I try running simple "wget https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu-iso/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso" as a test the speeds is around ~30-1500KB/s. While for the apt-get upgrade the speed is relatively normal, but fails as well. LAN speed is fine and is around 100MB/s.

If I try doing the same thing in a different VM, using 18.04LTS as well, behaviour is completely normal. Installs go through, speed is around 25MB/s which is in line with the connection I have.

I have not performed any hardware changes or configuration changes in the ESXI or the Ubuntu VM. Doing the "tests" above tells me this is a software issue and not a hardware one.

I've tried googling around and performed with no results.
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

```
panda@box:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-firmware
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 75.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.173.18 [75.1 MB]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.173.18
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:099bbc0f958db43fad328f9f09065e448a85dcdb126691c2dab040213af13e41
   - SHA1:31b98ad6e6d2ca49e1a5297d9913d0be41f2a965 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:60b003009991844b6f8cd73bc185989a [weak]
   - Filesize:75056824 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:0c404bce54ff28a87300f0ba933726ea7bc7008cc1edd4b8586f2f93a5bab2e8
   - SHA1:d5d35d984788d6e25b10abdaf09f33614dd1fa72 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:94495275aa23904b065cb37185d35b8e [weak]
   - Filesize:75056824 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 06 May 2020 15:18:25 +0000
Fetched 75.1 MB in 6s (12.6 MB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173.18_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:099bbc0f958db43fad328f9f09065e448a85dcdb126691c2dab040213af13e41
    - SHA1:31b98ad6e6d2ca49e1a5297d9913d0be41f2a965 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:60b003009991844b6f8cd73bc185989a [weak]
    - Filesize:75056824 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:0c404bce54ff28a87300f0ba933726ea7bc7008cc1edd4b8586f2f93a5bab2e8
    - SHA1:d5d35d984788d6e25b10abdaf09f33614dd1fa72 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:94495275aa23904b065cb37185d35b8e [weak]
    - Filesize:75056824 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 06 May 2020 15:18:25 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Hash sum mismatch is a problem with the mirror you are using.  Their files are time-inconsistent.  I have a local mirror and this crops up occasionally for users of it, to fix it I refresh the mirror. As you are using someone else's mirror, you just have to wait for it to catch up. I see you have searched this site for other fixes that will tell you to clear caches, etc, but they never worked for me either.  My local mirror draws from `us.archive.ubuntu.com` which is currently not having this problem, you could try pointing at that one.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Unfortunately, that did not help. Still results in

sudo apt-get update  
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]  
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1,019 kB]  
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [516 kB]  
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages [8,570 kB]  
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: So I manually installed the package, that was throwing errors. Downloading the file on a different VM (running on same hardware), uploading it throughWinSCP and then sing 
`sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file `

  However it still has not resolved the speed issues. Running speedtest in cli results in very subpar results compared to a different Ubuntu system on the same ESXi host.

Comment: That's interesting. I get wildly different results with speedtest-cli and ookla's own website. Especially on the upload. Frankly it seems like the website test is more accurate. But I get you are comparing apples to apples.

Comment: @OrganicMarble it ended up being a wrong cable, or at least it seems like it now, that i have replaced it.. How it could affect only VM is beyond me.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct way to fix name resolution from Docker container?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163/what-is-correct-way-to-fix-name-resolution-from-docker-container)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)