# Ubuntu inside Docker-container : apt-get update failure (Error writing to output file)

Tags: apt, docker, container

On my Docker platform, I created a container (`docker run -it --name UBUNTU ubuntu bash`)
and it works (Up + logged into as root)

But when I try to update repo with "apt-get update" I get :

```
root@a638632113f5:/# apt-get update
Get:1 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Err:1 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Get:2 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
Err:2 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Get:3 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Err:3 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Get:4 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Err:4 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
W: Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What does it mean ? (I guess it's not an issue with dns)

`/etc/apt/sources.list` seems up-to-date

`cat /etc/os-release` gives :

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Maybe that there is no space left on the device ?!

Comment: THX for your reply ! When df -hT I get /var = 100% ! so I probably have to extend this partition (My platform is a VM in fact and /var partition was sized automatically with 1.7GB wich is probably tto small...); I gonna rebuild my VM and send a feedback ! THX again

Comment: if you fixed your problem, you can write an answer.

Comment: @Rominou. You are asking **two** questions: 1. "What does it mean ?" (to which I _don't_ have an answer) and 2. "How to solve this issue ?" (to which I _do_ have an answer) . . . I think it would much increase your chances to get an answer if you remove _one_ of these two questions. How about removing the one that is less important to you?

Comment: I can easily reproduce your error, except in my case it doesn't say `Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]`. . . . . . . . . . . . . The error message I get is `Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]`. I have no idea why I get an error message which is different from yours, but I _**do**_ have a hunch that yours is rather misleading ... If you are observant, you will notice that your IP address and mine both start with 91.189.88. What does that tell you? Hint: https://en.ipshu.com/ip_d_list/91.189.88.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct way to fix name resolution from Docker container?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163/what-is-correct-way-to-fix-name-resolution-from-docker-container)

Comment: > _I guess it's not an issue with dns_ . . . - I respectfully disagree.