# can't run ubuntu 20.04 server on synology diskstation as docker container

Tags: 20.04

I have installed several ubuntu20.04 server images in my synology diskstation as a docker container. But i can't use the ssh comands as well as on a normal vps.
For example: after installing the ubuntu-server container, i go to the SSH-Terminal and try to run "apt-get update". But only errors are showing after long time waiting:
E: Failed to fetch h t t p : / /archive.ubuntu.co............
Also i want to install nano, but answer is: can not locate package......
Is the ubuntu container on a synology diskstation useless and unable to do anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct way to fix name resolution from Docker container?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163/what-is-correct-way-to-fix-name-resolution-from-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this is the right place to ask for support, because you are using Synology Diskstation.
Imho your problem is, that the docker container don't have internet access and can't fetch packages. This could be a network related problem in docker or e.w. a firewall problem in your diskstation.